# From object to array() - PHP

Tags: php, json

I have this piece of code:

```
return json_decode($body);
```

This return is from a function that gets from google some search results. If I print that it wil be for example:

```
stdClass Object
    (
        [responseData] => stdClass Object
            (
                [results] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => stdClass Object
                            (
                                [GsearchResultClass] => GwebSearch
                                [unescapedUrl] => http://www.bmw.com/
                                [url] => http://www.bmw.com/
                                [visibleUrl] => www.bmw.com
                                [cacheUrl] => http://www.google.com/search?q=cache:ys7v8m0j3LMJ:www.bmw.com
                                [title] => BMW automobiles - website of the BMW AG
                                [titleNoFormatting] => BMW automobiles - website of the BMW AG
                                [content] => The official BMW AG website: BMW automobiles, services, technologies and all about BMWs sheer driving pleasure.
                            )
                        [1] => stdClass Object
                            (
                                [GsearchResultClass] => GwebSearch
                                [unescapedUrl] => http://www.bmwusa.com/
                                [url] => http://www.bmwusa.com/
                                [visibleUrl] => www.bmwusa.com
                                [cacheUrl] => http://www.google.com/search?q=cache:W59Q9fpm9PkJ:www.bmwusa.com
                                [title] => BMW of North America, LLC
                                [titleNoFormatting] => BMW of North America, LLC
                                [content] => BMW ConnectedDrive. Reads Facebook posts and emails. Forecasts the weather. Maps routes. Parks your car. And much more. The All-New 6 Gran Coupe ...
                            )
                        [2] => stdClass Object
                            (
                                [GsearchResultClass] => GwebSearch
                                [unescapedUrl] => http://autos.yahoo.com/bmw/
                                [url] => http://autos.yahoo.com/bmw/
                                [visibleUrl] => autos.yahoo.com
                                [cacheUrl] => http://www.google.com/search?q=cache:yjHBrdiQI5UJ:autos.yahoo.com
                                [title] => New 2011, 2012 BMW Car Models - Yahoo! Autos
                                [titleNoFormatting] => New 2011, 2012 BMW Car Models - Yahoo! Autos
                                [content] => Yahoo! Autos - BMW Cars. Research all BMW 2012, 2011 car models. Compare new BMW vehicles; buy used BMWs for sale.
                            )
                        [3] => stdClass Object
                            (
                                [GsearchResultClass] => GwebSearch
                                [unescapedUrl] => http://www.motortrend.com/new_cars/01/bmw/
                                [url] => http://www.motortrend.com/new_cars/01/bmw/
                                [visibleUrl] => www.motortrend.com
                                [cacheUrl] => http://www.google.com/search?q=cache:8ur1ZNau24AJ:www.motortrend.com
                                [title] => New BMW Cars - Find 2012 2013 BMW Car Prices & Reviews ...
                                [titleNoFormatting] => New BMW Cars - Find 2012 2013 BMW Car Prices & Reviews ...
                                [content] => Matches 1 - 14 of 14 ... Find new BMW cars and 2012 2013 BMW cars at Motor Trend. Research a new BMW car, find BMW prices, read reviews, or buy a new ...
                            )
                    )
                [cursor] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [resultCount] => 16,700,000
                        [pages] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => stdClass Object
                                    (
                                        [start] => 0
                                        [label] => 1
                                    )
                                [1] => stdClass Object
                                    (
                                        [start] => 4
                                        [label] => 2
                                    )
                                [2] => stdClass Object
                                    (
                                        [start] => 8
                                        [label] => 3
                                    )
                                [3] => stdClass Object
                                    (
                                        [start] => 12
                                        [label] => 4
                                    )
                                [4] => stdClass Object
                                    (
                                        [start] => 16
                                        [label] => 5
                                    )
                                [5] => stdClass Object
                                    (
                                        [start] => 20
                                        [label] => 6
                                    )
                                [6] => stdClass Object
                                    (
                                        [start] => 24
                                        [label] => 7
                                    )
                                [7] => stdClass Object
                                    (
                                        [start] => 28
                                        [label] => 8
                                    )
                            )
                        [estimatedResultCount] => 16700000
                        [currentPageIndex] => 0
                        [moreResultsUrl] => http://www.google.com/search?oe=utf8&ie=utf8&source=uds&start=0&hl=en&q=bmw+cars
                        [searchResultTime] => 0.15
                    )
            )
        [responseDetails] => 
        [responseStatus] => 200
    )
```

Now, I tried to get with the function `get_object_vars()` but the same output will come. I want to put into an array the values but only the `[ur] => ;` `[title] =>` and `[content]=> ;` how can i achieve that?

Comment: Please read your question after you write it. Can you understand that huge lump of output in it's current form? Because I can't...

Comment: First, no one can probably see which `url`, `title` etc you want from that chunk of code. Secondly, it is an object. You can simply access it's properties with `obj->url`, or `obj->sub_obj->url`, depending on which level the value is. For that to know you have to inspect the response and figure it out. That is basic PHP and should not be a problem. If you are more comfortable with arrays, pass `true` as second parameter to `json_decode`.

Comment: Please, please, apply some formatting ...

Comment: This is not a real question. You are asking how to access object properties, which is basic knowledge. Please go the PHP Manual and familiarize yourself with how objects work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the data above is held in a variable called `$returnedData`:

This version works if you use `return json_decode($body);`:

```
$results = array();
foreach ($returnedData->responseData->results as $result) {
  $results[] = array(
    'url' => $result->url,
    'title' => $result->title,
    'content'=>$result->content
  );
}

print_r($results);
```

...and this version works if you use `return json_decode($body,true);`:

```
$results = array();
foreach ($returnedData['responseData']['results'] as $result) {
  $results[] = array(
    'url' => $result['url'],
    'title' => $result['title'],
    'content'=>$result['content']
  );
}

print_r($results);
```

Comment: The thing si that to me it returns like an object, and if i put the `json_decode($json,true)` it wil give the array an in both cases `responsedata` and `results` will not be found.

Comment: It worked. Thanks. You saved me a lot of headache. Thanku again.

Answer (score 0):

> mixed json_decode ( string $json [, bool $assoc = false [, int $depth
>   = 512 [, int $options = 0 ]]] )

Just set the second argument to `true` ;)

Answer (score 0):

use `true` as an argument in [`json_decode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)  like below

```
var_dump(json_decode($json, true));
```

> assoc =  TRUE, returned objects will be converted into associative
>   arrays.